# Background Image Does not Stretch

Tags: html, css

I recieved this code looking for how to stretch background image in HTML for the  part of my page, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
< style type="text/css">


<!--
body {
    background-image: url(at4.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
         width: 100%;

 }
 -->
 </style>
```

Comment: you commented those things remove the css comment from body to end <!-- -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (CSS3):

`background-size:cover` (will crop) or `background-size: 100%;` (will stretch)

Cross browser solution (< IE9)

http://jsfiddle.net/4gBXS/

```
#background {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size: 100%;`

This will stretch your background image.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aY3BV/)**

**The Code:**

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;

 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, you can set the background-size :

```
body {
   background-size: 100%; 
}
```

It will work on Chrome >= 3.0, Firefox >= 3.6, IE >= 9.0 and Opera >= 10.

[Here's a **JSFiddle** some examples of the property.](http://jsfiddle.net/VpHK4/)